# Bring javascript calendar control to the front?

Tags: html, css

I have two javascript date pickers on my asp.net site:
[image]

When I click the from date picker, it looks like this:
[image]

As you can see, the calendar pop-up appears behind the next set of fields on the screen.

My question is, what can I do to make this control appear in front of (or, over, rather) the fields on the screen?

EDIT:
Here is the code for this particular date picker:

```
<td rowspan="2" style="background-color: #A5C2FA; padding-left: 1px; text-align: center;">
  <a onclick=" showCalendarControl(txtFromDate) " href="#">
  <img src="../images/calendar.gif" style="height: 20px; width: 20px;" border="0" alt="Calendar" /></a>
 </td>
```

And here is my CSS (I've added the z-index change for ui-datepicker, but it's doesn't appear to help):

```
<style type="text/css">
    .body
    {
        background-color: #006699;
    }

    .outermost_body
    {
        background: White;
        border-color: Black;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 2px;
        height: 120px;
        left: 10px;
        position: absolute;
        text-align: left;
        top: 200px;
        width: 700px;
    }

    .outermost_grid
    {
        height: 320px;
        left: 10px;
        position: absolute;
        text-align: left;
        top: 200px;
        width: 500px;
    }

    .searchTable
    {
        background-color: #C9EAF3;
        left: 5px;
        padding: 1px;
        position: absolute;
        text-align: left;
        top: 50px;
        width: 700px;
        z-index: 900;
    }

    .fieldcellText input
    {
        background-color: #D7E5F2;
        border: 1px solid #284279;
        color: #102132;
        font: 11px Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        margin-left: 0px;
        width: 150px;
    }

    .ui-datepicker
    {
        z-index: 999;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: That is a CSS (zindex) problem, post the CSS code here

Comment: you need to set the `z-index` of the calender control. It's a CSS issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`z-index` works only on positioned elements

`position:absolute`, `position:relative`, or `position:fixed`

try this,

```
.ui-datepicker{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1001;
}
```

Comment: Hey, I appreciate the help.  I went through my CSS and anywhere I found a z-index, I changed it so that it was less than the z-index of datepicker.  Unfortunately, it didn't help.  But, I'm pretty sure this has to be the issue.  I inherited this code, so I'm not fully familiar with it.  I'll continue to research how to fix this problem.  Thank you!

Comment: Just an update, I think my problem is because the datepicker control is inside an update panel.  Everything I've read so far seems to indicate that having a datepicker control in an update panel is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set the z-index of the datepicker.
Try adding this to the bottom of your css sheet.

```
.ui-datepicker {
  z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: Hey, I appreciate the help. I went through my CSS and anywhere I found a z-index, I changed it so that it was less than the z-index of datepicker. Unfortunately, it didn't help. But, I'm pretty sure this has to be the issue. I inherited this code, so I'm not fully familiar with it. I'll continue to research how to fix this problem. Thank you!

Comment: Try loading the page in chrome and inspecting the datepicker element via the context menu.  After you have done this you can see which style elements are currently active for that element. This should tell you if something is not as you expect it so you can track down the problem.  Good luck!